# spring web and spring batch compatibility?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I have a project in the company that is running with spring web, they asked me for a batch job in which they want to implement spring batch. I have tried to elaborate it but it always gives me an error The web server cannot be started.
I would like to know if spring web is compatible with spring batch running at the same time in the same project

Comment: *"it always gives me an error"* Then you did something wrong. --- That answer is as detailed as the question. Was that helpful? No? Then perhaps you should provide more detail. You know, perhaps showing the error *in the question* might be a good start. Please see the [**Help Center**](https://stackoverflow.com/help) article "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: *FYI:* A simple web search for [`spring batch mvc`](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+batch+mvc) will find you lots of articles about using both at the same time, so if you have done just a microscopic amount of research on your own, your question would have already been answered by yourself: **Yes**, they are compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are compatible. Can you post the error that you got?

By the way, consider to use @Schedule on you project, if it's possible.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
public void executeJob() {

}
```

In some cases, it resolves the problem and you don't need to put a middleware to increase complexity to you business.

Comment: Also, if it's a spring boot application, you need to put @EnableScheduling on you main class.

Comment: thanks for you answer